# How to set two different colors for a single string in itext

Tags: itext

I have string like below, and i can't split the string.

```
String result="Developed By : Mr.XXXXX";
```

i can create a paragraph in itext and set font with color like below,

```
Font dataGreenFont = FontFactory.getFont("Garamond", 10,Color.GREEN);
preface.add(new Paragraph(result, dataGreenFont));
```

it set the green color to entire text `result` but i want to set color only for `Mr.XXXXX` part. How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First this: [you are using an obsolete version of iText. Please upgrade!](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq)

As for your question: a `Paragraph` consists of a series of `Chunk` objects. A `Chunk` is an atomic part of text in which all the glyphs are in the same font, have the same font size, color, etc...

Hence you need to split your `String` in two parts:

```
Font dataGreenFont = FontFactory.getFont("Garamond", 10, BaseColor.GREEN);
Font dataBlackFont = FontFactory.getFont("Garamond", 10, BaseColor.BLACK);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Chunk("Developed By : ", dataGreenFont));
p.Add(new Chunk("Mr.XXXXX", dataBlackFont));
document.add(p);
```

Comment: `Chunk` is replaced with `Text` in the latest version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501128/what-replaces-chunk-in-itext-7