# What replaces chunk in iText 7?

Tags: java, itext7

Attempting to use iText 7 in java.  Want to have part of a paragraph be bold.  Apparently in earlier releases this was done by formatting "chunks" separately then adding them to the paragraph.  Apparently "chunks" don't exist in iText 7.  What is the procedure for iText 7?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Text` in `com.itextpdf.layout.element` is meant to be an alternative for `Chunk`.

To make a part of a paragraph bold, you would need a bold font to be specified for a piece of a text.

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(new Text("this will be in bold").setFont(boldFont));
```

Alternatively, you can rely on iText to simulate bold for regular font, but this is not a preferred way.

```
p.add(new Text("bold will be simulated for regular font").setBold());
```

Please check out the [jumpstart tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial) written by Bruno Lowagie.

Comment: @OldAndTired, please kindly accept the answer if that is what you were looking for