# What is the replacement for Chunk.NEWLINE in itext7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Chunk.NEWLINE adds an new line in iText 5. But iText 7 do not support Chunk. How do I add a new line using iText 7?

Comment: One of these answers (not the highest voted) may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158336/how-to-insert-blank-lines-in-pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert blank lines in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158336/how-to-insert-blank-lines-in-pdf)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37502999/2333458) answer about replacement of `Chunk` in iText7. Now to add a new line you should use `new Text("\n")` and put it to a paragraph.

Comment: That helps. Thanks.!