# How to give a empty new line in itext7?

Tags: c#, itext

I had tried to use the following line to add an empty line in itext7:

```
doc.add(CHUNK.Newline)
```

This works in iTextSharp but not in itext7. What should I use here?

Comment: I've removed your `visual-studio` tag for you. It is only meant for tags relating to issues with Visual Studio itself, not code that was written in Visual Studio. Please read the tag usage descriptions (see [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more info) so that you don't misuse tags in future.

Comment: Check this: [iText7: How to add a full line break?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/getting-started/itext7-how-add-full-line-break)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the replacement for Chunk.NEWLINE in itext7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818091/what-is-the-replacement-for-chunk-newline-in-itext7)